# What is the netstat command for particular port if that's connected or not?

Tags: macos, terminal

Need to know what is the exact netstat command to find out if a port is connected with any network or it's open through OS X Terminal. I want info on a particular port, such as port number 80, so the netstat command should include the port number.

Comment: Do you mean `netstat -tulpen`? (This assumes you are talking about TCP ports. Also you might drop the u-param. It will show UDP connections.)

Comment: no that didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by `testate`?

Comment: see I have edited..that was a typo

Comment: @semicoder Oops, wrong OS... Use `sudo netstat -al`

Comment: `Administrators-MacBook-Pro-2:~ soudip$ netstat -tulpen
netstat: en: unknown or uninstrumented protocol
Administrators-MacBook-Pro-2:~ soudip$ `

Comment: hey I want a info on a particular port... like say port number 80. so the netstat command should include the port number..

Comment: @semicoder I'm going to put a brief hold on this. Could you edit the post to be very specific about why netstat is needed? Wouldn't `lsof` show you the ports that are being listened on? Also, OS X has launchd which can register to listen on ports so you don't necessarily know what program will respond or get launched. Better to describe your problem in more detail rather than asking how to use "netstat" or some other tool if that's just the one you think will solve your end problem. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem for the **XY problem dilemma**.

Comment: @bmike I have to create a big, shiny bookmark to this meta-xy-problem-page -  or even better I make it my browser's start page ;-)

Comment: @klanomath Indeed - I love this phrasing so much ***"the solution that you ask for help with might have no obvious connections to the problem that you are actually trying to solve"***

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best you can get is

```
netstat -f inet -n | grep .port
```

or

```
netstat -f inet | grep .servicename
```

Examples:

```
machine:~ user$ netstat -f inet -n | grep .443
tcp4       0      0  192.168.114.5.58471       192.111.0.25.443       ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.114.5.57990       192.111.0.25.443       ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.114.5.56813       192.111.0.25.443       ESTABLISHED

machine:~ user$ netstat -f inet | grep .https
tcp4       0      0  machine.example.co.58471 stackoverflow.co.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  machine.example.co.57990 stackoverflow.co.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  machine.example.co.56813 stackoverflow.co.https ESTABLISHED
```

Please consider that using port numbers below 256 in the first command may collide with one or more of the 4 octets of IP-numbers.

Comment: It's working for 443 port..But when I am giving 631 port it's not working.. Why is that?? @klanomath

Comment: you whether need a running service on port 631 (ipp/cups) on your Mac or a server you are connected to with an open port 631. In my opinion the tool you are really looking for is [nmap](https://nmap.org/book/inst-macosx.html).

Comment: Can you elaborate a little.. about this tool??
And, there is `findstr` command for _**windows cmd**_ with **netstat**..
No _mac equivalent_ of such is there???

Comment: It's an advanced port scanner/security scanner check the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap)

Comment: And, there is findstr command for **windows cmd** with netstat.. No mac equivalent of such is there???

Comment: Windows netstat | findstr = Unix/OS X netstat | grep

Answer (score 0):

You need nmap, it's an ideal tool for this.

- [The official website.](https://nmap.org)
- [The download link.](https://nmap.org/dist/nmap-6.49BETA4-2.dmg)

Now check to see if downloads from unidentified developers are allowed in *System Preferences* in the *Security & Privacy* section. If not – allow them.

Now run the installer (I highly recommend that you ***do not*** install *ZenMap* alongside), and now you can run nmap from the command line.

Open up the Terminal app and type the following:

> sudo nmap -vv -sV 127.0.0.1

...then hit *return* and type in your password.

**In case** you don't know what the command means (don't take it personally):

> sudo **=** Super User DO to execute commands as the most privileged
>   user (requires password)
>
> -vv **=** verbose (how much info will be displayed while it is scanning)
>
> -sV **=** port and service scan
>
> 127.0.0.1 **=** localhost, your local machine address

Wait a few moments and the result should give you a detailed summary of the scan results, with the ports and services (and their versions) being at the very top of the conclusive results.